# JQuery Change CSS Display not working

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have this working on chrome and firefox basically when the user clicks on a sub image it changes the main image by altering it's display property from hide to show. Here's my img elements.

```
<img id="lg1" src="http...
<img id="lg2" style="display:none" src="http...
<img id="lg3" style="display:none" src="http...
```

and my js looks like this:

```
    $('#graph1').click(function() {
    $("#lg1").css("display","inherit");
    $("#lg2").css("display","none");
    $("#lg3").css("display","none");
});

$('#graph2').click(function() {
    $("#lg1").css("display","none");
    $("#lg2").css("display","inherit");
    $("#lg3").css("display","none");
});

$('#graph3').click(function() {
    $("#lg1").css("display","none");
    $("#lg2").css("display","none");
    $("#lg3").css("display","inherit");
});
```

In IE I get this error:

```
Could not get the display property. Invalid argument.
```

Is there anyway I could alter my code to make it work with Chrome, FF and IE?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any way you could change Inherit to something else? Whats it inheriting from? ie. display: block

Comment: why can't you use `display: inline` (or `display: block`)?

Comment: IE 8 preferably, but IE 7 would be nice :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"inherit" is not a valid display value on IE, unfortunately. You could try "", it should work ([live example](http://jsbin.com/etuco3)) barring some stylesheet rule saying otherwise for that element ([like this](http://jsbin.com/etuco3/2)).

Off-topic, but if you want a shorter way to write `.css("display", "none")` you can use `.hide()` instead. :-)